# Replacing a string with a string using regex

Tags: regex

I'm very naive user for regex. I got an important task in limited time. I hope someone could look into it. Meanwhile I'll be trying from myside.

I've strings like

```
#: [Section]zNone
msgctxt "[Section]zNone"
msgid "None"
msgstr "Ninguno"

#: [Section]Search
msgid "Search"
msgstr "Búsquedas"

#: [Section]AdvancedSearch
msgid "Advanced Search"
msgstr "Búsqueda Avanzada"
```

For all msgstr"bla bla bla" strings should be replaced by msgstr "" using regex in file replace & find.

Comment: What language/tool are you using for this?

Comment: @anubhava..In sublime text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this I suppose

```
(?<=msgstr\s)"(.*)"
```

and replace with `""`

http://regex101.com/r/hM3gN9

Comment: good one. I was typing the same, when you answered this one :)

Comment: @aelor.. Thanks pal. Worked like a charm

Comment: @AmitJoki haha you are late :P

Comment: Thank you guys. It saved time a lot for me. I mean it.